# How to create jar for Junit test class

Tags: java, maven

I am following Maven package structure.In my project we have class like `PayloadProcessorTest.java` and it has some dependencies

I want to create a jar file for PayloadProcessorTest with dependencies

Can any one please help me to create a jar with dependencies

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2-beta-2</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>create-test-dependency</id>
      <phase>process-test-classes</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>single</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <finalName>classloader-test-deps</finalName>
        <attach>false</attach>
        <descriptors>
          <descriptor>src/main/assembly/test-assembly.xml</descriptor>
        </descriptors>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

This is the content of test-assembly.xml

```
<assembly>
  <id>test-classloader</id>
  <formats>
    <format>jar</format>
  </formats>
  <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
  <fileSets>
    <fileSet>
      <directory>${project.build.testOutputDirectory}</directory>
      <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
      <!--modify/add include to match your package(s) -->
      <includes>
        <include>com/test/**</include>
      </includes>
    </fileSet>
  </fileSets>
</assembly>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this maven plugin [Maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). As the documentation said "This plugin provides the capability to package the artifact in an uber-jar"

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>.settings/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>*.classpath</exclude>
                                    <exclude>*.project</exclude>
                                    <exclude>*.txt</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.My class PayloadProcessorTest.java has some dependencies means my class methods calling some other class methods and those classes connected to database by using properties file configurations. I need all those classes and dependents to a jar. I used maven-assembly plugin but it created jar for only PayloadProcessorTest.class.I am updating my plugin above. can you plase tell me how can i get jar for PayloadProcessorTest with all dipendent classes

Comment: Instead of assembly, did you use this plugin and did you do "mvn package"? Doing that, you get the jar with dependencies